# How to add column to datagridview using AddRange c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i saw people use this below code to add many column at a time. here is code

```
        var col3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        var col4 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();

        col3.HeaderText = "Column3";
        col3.Name = "Column3";

        col4.HeaderText = "Column4";
        col4.Name = "Column4";

        dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] {col3,col4});
```

but my situation is bit different. this way i am adding column to `datagridview` in loop.

```
foreach (DataColumn column in retriever.Columns)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column.ColumnName, column.ColumnName);
}
```

anyone can tell me how to modify my above code to use `addrange() instead of add()` function. my intention is to add all columns at a time instead of adding loop.

Comment: You could create an array of columns, use the foreach loop to fill it and then use the AddRange() with the filled array as argument.

Comment: performance will increase if i follow that approach?

Comment: There will be no real difference in term of performance, if the DataGridView is empty when you add columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use linq `Select` statement:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(retriever.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(n => new DataGridViewColumn
{
    Name = n.ColumnName,
    HeaderText = n.ColumnName
}));
```

but the most optimally will be foreach:

```
retriever.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToList().ForEach(n => dataGridView1.Columns.Add(n.ColumnName, n.ColumnName));
```

It merely examples of the solution in another way. In my opinion your current method of initializing this list is entirely correct.

Comment: retriever columns property return `DataColumnCollection` so it does not support tolist() or select(0 function. so guide me what to do? thanks

Comment: I updated the answer. You can use Cast() method to say what type of collection

Comment: i use your current one but getting error `The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>
(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TResult>)' 
cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: You have to add a return keyword, sorry.

Comment: inside lambda expression

Comment: i am using your first code and i saw there is no return code. would u mind to see again bcoz again i copy your code and get the same error.

Comment: now i copied your second code and it works but what need to change in your first code to make it compile. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83541/discussion-between-pawel-maga-and-mou).

Comment: your first code still giving compilation error. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
DataGridViewColumn[] column_array = new DataGridViewColumn[retriever.Columns.Count];

    for (int cnt = 0;cnt < retriever.Columns.Count;cnt++)
    {
        DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewColumn();
        col.Name = retriever.Columns[cnt].Name;
        col.HeaderText = retriever.Columns[cnt].HeaderText;
        column_array[cnt] = col;
    }

     dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(column_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You may change your code to something like that:

```
DataGridViewColumn[] arr = 
retriever.Columns.Select(d=>new DataGridViewColumn()
{Name = d.ColumnName,HeaderText = d.ColumnName}).ToArray();
dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(arr);
```